# ComboBox doesn't allow user input

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

My problem is that ComboBox doesn't allow user input (even if I set IsTextEditable to true) if ValueMember and DisplayMember are same class fields.

**update** - I can't type anything in combobox (even if I set ValueMember and DisplayMember to different fields)

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit IsTextEditable="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPartners}" DisplayMember="Id" ValueMember="Id"
                  EditValue="{Binding Invoice.PartnerId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

ListOfPartners is BindingList.

Comment: what do you have, what do you want, what have you tried....
Questions....

Comment: can you post some code (XAML and your converter)?

Comment: I updated post with code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is: AutoComplete="True"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a set (mutator) on the public property?